# Unpredictable behaviour with a square root function in Julia

Tags: function, for-loop, functional-programming, julia

I made a simple function which calculates the square root of numbers for a given range. If x is negative, the function stops and throws and error message. This is the code:

```
   function square(x::Int,y::Int) 
        for i in range(x,y)
            if i< 0
                print("You can't enter non-negative numbers. Please enter a valid number for x.")
                break
            else i>=0
                println(sqrt.(i))
            end
        end
    end
```

The problem arises when I use the function for a valid range. For example, when I call the function range(0,9) I got this:

```
square(0,9)

0.0
1.0
1.4142135623730951
1.7320508075688772
2.0
2.23606797749979
2.449489742783178
2.6457513110645907
2.8284271247461903
```

Then, when I call for

```
square(2,9)

1.4142135623730951
1.7320508075688772
2.0
2.23606797749979
2.449489742783178
2.6457513110645907
2.8284271247461903
3.0
3.1622776601683795
```

I tried so many combinations and just in few cases the function works as expected (for example with range 1:9). 
Could somebody please explain me what am I doing wrong and how can I fix the problem?
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: What is `Union{Float64, Int}` accomplishing for you if you only iterate over the integers.

Comment: I changed the arguments' type and problem is still occuring.

Comment: Is the function  range doing what you expect it to? It seems that the second argument specifies the number of values, not the end point. Some discussion around this is given here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/25896

Answer (score 4):

As @Fredrik Bagge mentions in the comments, `range(x,y)` isn't doing what you expect it to. Looking at the docs via `?range` we see that

> ```
> range(start, [step], length)
> ```
>
> Construct a range by length, given a starting value and optional step (defaults to 1).

So the second integer argument specifies the length of the range and not the endpoint. What you want to do use is either `start:step:range` syntax or `linspace(start, stop, numberofpoints)`.

Using the latter (with `numberofpoints=10` for example) your function would read

```
function square(x::Int,y::Int) 
    for i in linspace(x,y,10)
        if i< 0
            print("You can't enter non-negative numbers. Please enter a valid number for x.")
            break
        else i>=0
            println(sqrt.(i))
        end
    end
end
```

However, broadcasting in `sqrt.(i)` doesn't make much sense because `i` is a single number. I'd probably rather do something like this

```
function square2(x::Int,y::Int)
    (x<0 || y<0) && error("You can't enter non-negative numbers. Please enter a valid number for x.")
    sqrt.(linspace(x,y,10))
end
```

**Note** that in this [pull request](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/25896#issuecomment-365442532) the `range` methods have been overhauled and `linspace` has been deprecated for Julia 0.7.

Comment: Note that your edit really isn't correct. The `collect` function does not solve (and has nothing to do with) your problem. What matters is that you switched from `range(x,y)` to `x:y`, which I btw mentioned in my answer as `start:step:stop`. Even without calling `collect` your code will work as expected. In fact, collect shouldn't be used here as you shouldn't collect (i.e. allocate) the full unit range just for iterating over it.

Comment: On a general note, if you think to have found an answer to your own question you should consider posting it as an answer as well rather than editing your original question. This is more transparent and allows people to upvote and comment on your answer directly. Also it would allow you to accept your own answer if you think it is the best one given. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thank you for the observation. I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you need to write a function like this. You can just write

```
sqrt.(x:y)
```

and just use that. If you need to print the number to screen in some particular way, do something like this:

```
function square(x::Int,y::Int) 
    for i in x:y
        if i < 0
            println("You can't enter non-negative numbers. Please enter a valid number for x.")
            return
        else
           println(sqrt(i))
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I want a function which returns a pair of numbers X - sqrt(X) in order to plot them.

Comment: Why do you need a function for that? Can't you just do `plot(x, sqrt.(x))`?

Comment: It's kind of an assignment for an online course I'm taking. They require us to write a function and then plot the results.

Comment: Sounds like a strange assignment, but it's a bit hard to tell. Good luck.

Answer (score -3):

In Julia collect works as range in languages such as Python and R. Maybe the solution is not so elegant, but works as expected:

```
   function square(x::Int,y::Int) 
        for i in collect(x:y)
            if i< 0
                print("You can't enter non-negative numbers. Please enter a valid number for x.")
                break
            else i>=0
                return sqrt.(collect(x:y))
            end
        end
    end 

square(1,25)
```

Comment: This answer completely misunderstands all the previous comments and answers. You should _not_ use `collect`, and it makes no sense to use the iteration variable `i`, and then ignore it in the statement `return sqrt.(collect(x:y))`